# Please help me convert my MySQL to MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

Will someone please explain to me and assist to convert my old code into the new MySQLi format? I would greatly appreciate it.

This is what my current code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Last 10 Results</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Name</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "root");
            if (!$connect) {
                die(mysql_error());
            }
            mysql_select_db("apploymentdevs");
            $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM demo LIMIT 10 ORDER BY Id");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Id']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Name']?></td>
                </tr>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Again I appreciate the assistance.

This is what I have done ( I am so sorry I am such a noob )

```
                    <?php
                        // Database details
                        $dbhost = 'localhost';
                        $dbuser = '#';
                        $dbpass = '#';
                        $dbname = '#';
                        $db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
                        if($db->connect_errno > 0){
                            die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
                        }
                        $results = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM formdata LIMIT 10 ORDER BY id");
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row['ID']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['FullName']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Mobile']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Email']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['Province']?></td>
                            </tr>

                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
```

Comment: have you not tried anything?

Comment: I have but I am too ashamed to add it

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have added what I thought was right, but please don't yell at me I am learning.

Comment: got something for ya down there ;-)

Comment: I want to upvote, but I cant because everyone down voted my legit question I now don't have the rep required to give back a upvote for the person who assisted me

Comment: To YCS, get away from the earth, you're polluting it.

Comment: Is the  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))  part correct thou?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update this line:

```
$results = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM formdata LIMIT 10 ORDER BY id");
```

to

```
$results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM formdata ORDER BY id LIMIT 10");
```

Comment: I have a pretty good feeling who downvoted us. There's a "snake" amongst us.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, both you and Fred, Is my mysqli_fetch_array part correct?

Comment: Yes, that part is correct, although it can take an optional parameter. But it is ok as it is.

Comment: Dammit I get this error now: 

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/test/public_html/backend.php on line 650

Comment: Suggestions: 1. check your table names. 2. Run the code in PhpMyAdmin. 3. Put the `ORDER BY` statement before the `LIMIT` statement.

Comment: @ErikThiart `on line 650`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- got to be a very long one, you bet.

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer the error doesn't support the question now.

Comment: You sir are a genius !! The issue was number 3. ( Do I need to close this query or will it stop automatically? )

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer aaaahhh!!! I didn't notice LIMIT before ORDER BY - that totally evaded me. That needs to be edited in your answer though.

Comment: Just mark the answer as the accepted answer, that should do.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer do I need to close the connection afterwards? If so how would one do that? There is other scripts writing to the DB on other pages.

Comment: @ErikThiart, if the connection was not opened as a persistent connection, it will be automatically closed. However, if you need to explicitly close it, you can do so by calling: `mysqli_close($db)`.

Comment: Excuse this noob question to follow... Where must I add mysqli_close($db); ie Between this part?                         <?php
                        }
                        ?>

Comment: A good place is after the `while` loop, just before the closing `?>`.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli

Comment: where did you add the code?

Comment: I added it before the first `?>` I also tried to add it before the second `?>`

Comment: I moved it till after the `}` in the last `<?php ?>` block seemed to work! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

The problem here, is that you haven't passed the connection to your query

```
$results = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT 
                        ^^^^
```

Read the documentation:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Unlike `mysql_`, it must be passed as a parameter.

Then make sure your query isn't failing.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

---

**Edit:**

Footnote:

As caught by NaijaProgrammer in a comment to the OP, LIMIT goes after ORDER BY and was a complete oversight on my part.

*"Suggestions: 1. check your table names. 2. Run the code in PhpMyAdmin. 3. Put the ORDER BY statement before the LIMIT statement. –  NaijaProgrammer"*

Reference for SELECT:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Example from the manual:

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
    [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
    [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

I would like to point out though that, you're using a lowercase here for the "id" `ORDER BY id` and that shouldn't be an issue for the ORDER BY.

***However,*** there is a difference between `$row['ID']` and `$row['id']`. If your database is configured to be case sensitive, then you will need to write the ID in lowercase.

Comment: when someone says "I'm such a noob", many times, they don't fully grasp the official PHP manual, which is the reason they probably came to SO in the first place. Then also, they usually would prefer the code fully written out for them. I'm speaking from experience.

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer It's understandable. I too was a newbie once, and I didn't know what to Google for. We're talking many years ago of course ;-)

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer I noticed your answer got a downvote :( that was NOT me, I can assure you of that. I even got one too.

Comment: @Fred-ii- not to worry, getting a downvote shows that someone at least read my post, I'm cool with that.

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer I like your style ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I suppose it's time for me to say "I like your style ;-)"

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer thanks ;-) glad to see the OP accepted your answer, *cheers*. I'm just doing a few more edits in regards to clarification and a few other things I spotted in the OP's question/code.